# TComboBox dropdown list should be hidden when the parent content is scrolled

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, tcombobox

Take a `TComboBox` and put it on a `TScrollBox`. In the `OnMouseWheel` event of the `TScrollBox`, the position of the vertical scroll bar is adjusted as follows:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::ScrollBox1MouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta,
          TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
    ScrollBox1->VertScrollBar->Position = ScrollBox1->VertScrollBar->Position - WheelDelta;
    Handled = true;
}
```

If the drop-down list of the `TComboBox` is expanded, and you scroll outside the `TComboBox` with the mouse wheel, the `TComboBox` moves, but the drop-down list remains at the previous position.

I found an old-fashioned Windows 10 OS form and the `TComboBox` there shows the same behavior, so this seems to be default.

A simple way is to set the `DroppedDown` property of the `TComboBox` in the `OnMouseWheel` event to false. However, the `TComboBox` is not known in the actual application. So you would have to search for a corresponding `TComboBox` in the control list of the `TScrollBox`.

Ideally, the behavior should be like the default behavior when you click something outside the `TComboBox`, which hides the drop-down list. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how this is implemented in the VCL.

Do you have an idea how this could be realized?

Comment: Which Delphi/C++Builder version are you using? Testing in XE7 (Delphi) on Win10 I can not reproduce what you describe. The Combobox dropdown is closed immediately when clicking anything outside that dropdown. The dropdown stays open as long you dont click on anything. Scrolling the scrollbox is not possible with the mousewheel as long as the combo has focus (and its dropdown is open). Or maybe I misunderstood your issue?

Comment: I am using 11.3 Alexandria. The OnMouseWheel event of the form is fired even if the ComboBox has the focus. However, this is not the case when the mouse is inside the drop-down list.

Answer (score 1):

As you already noted TComboBox closes its dropdown list if it loses focus so you could programmatically switch focus to your ScrollBox for instance using

```
ScrollBox1->SetFocus;
```

EDIT: As you have noted in the comment below clicking anywhere outside ComboBox dropped down list closes it.

That is because when TCobmoBox dropdown list is shown it registers mouse capture so that next mouse click message is handled by the dropped down list directly. So if the click occurs inside dropdown list the appropriate list item is selected. If not dropdown list is closed. This even prevents clicking on Close button of your window.

So you could in theory simulate mouse click for instance using using

```
sendMessage(Form2.Handle,WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MakeLParam(0, 0));
sendMessage(Form2.Handle,WM_LBUTTONUP,   0, MakeLParam(0, 0));
```

But simulating user input in this manner is not considered as good practice. Instead it is recommended to use UI automation which might not lead to desired results in this case.

---

There is another way. You could use OnDropDown event of your combo boxes to store reference to the combo box that has its dropdown list shown in some global variable. Then in MouseScroll event you just use that reference to change DroppedDown property of the specific combo box to false which would then hide its dropdown list.

Comment: If you click only on the background (e.g.  TForm, or Panel), the ComboBox does not lose focus. The dropdown list will be closed anyway.